# Using variable in different classes

Tags: java, class

I have two seperate classes, one where i actually do the calculation of the area of a square like the first bit below, and one where I display the result but the one were i display the result is giving me an error saying that it can't find the "computeSquareArea" symbol. Why is it doing this and not transferring between classes?

```
public double computeSquareArea(double length)
{
    return length * length;
}


double sqArea = computeSquareArea(length);
System.out.println("Area of the square is " + sqArea);
```

Comment: Call your function with objects I guess.

Comment: show your entire class.

Answer (score 1):

Non-static methods belong to the instance of the object, while static methods belong to the class.

In your code, `computeSquareArea()` is a non-static method. This means that in order to call it, you must call it on an instance of the class that it is in.

If you want to be able to call the method without requiring an instance first, you can use a static method. In order to make the method static, change `public double computeSquareDistance()` to `public static double computeSquareDistance()`

You can read more about this [here.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi8ubCHzo7SAhUeHGMKHTh5A-gQFghNMAs&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F3903537%2Fi-want-to-know-the-difference-between-static-method-and-non-static-method&usg=AFQjCNEaZwsexFBXOufxr5F5zBk0nd9aLw)

Comment: even after adding the static im having the same issue. Do i have to construct an object in my other class in order to use it in the first one?

Comment: Let's say `computeSquareArea()` is in a class called Foo. In order to call the method from another class, you should call `Foo.computeSquareArea()`. If this isn't working for you, try posting the actual code, so we can further help you.

Comment: The issue isn't really static vs. non-static.  You need to call the method appropriately.  If it's static, the appropriate way is `className.methodName()`.  If it's not static, the appropriate way is `instanceRef.methodName()`.  If you call simply `methodName()`, the method must be defined in the same class where the call occurs.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, your method `computeSquareArea(double length)` is not static. So I guess you need to `Intantiate` the class that have your method `computeSquareArea(double length)`. Like for Example, lets assume your **Class** Name is `SomeClass`.

```
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
double sqArea = someClass.computeSquareArea(length); // This would be the method of your newly created Instance of SomeClass
System.out.println("Area of the square is " + sqArea);
```